# VS2010 Designer Z-Order

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, designer

I'm trying to change the z-order for some docked panel in the VS2010 designer. However, everytime I save the designer, close it down and re-open it, the z-order has reverted back to how it was before I changed it.

I've tried using the document outline, and the SendToBack context menu but both behave in the same way. I've also noticed that in another solution where it does work, the .designer.cs file doesn't actually change (I assumed control adding order would dictate z-order).

Is there any other way I can do this? I really don't want to do this at runtime...

**EDIT**

```
this.mainPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
this.mainPanel.Controls.Add(this.pnlRangeSelector);
this.mainPanel.Controls.Add(this.headerAndFooterRowCounts);
```

pnlRangeSelector has Dock.Top
headerAndFooterRowCounts has Dock.Right

when this renders however, headerAndFooterRowCounts takes the entire right side of it's parent panel, while pnlRangeSelector takes the Left portion.

That suggests to me that the pnlRangeSelector isn't correctly at the back like it's supposed to be.

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
int i = 0;
String output = String.Empty;
foreach (var c in this.mainPanel.Controls)
{
    if (c == pnlRangeSelector) { output += "RangeSelector at : " + i.ToString() + "\r\n"; }
    else if (c == this.headerAndFooterRowCounts) { output += "HeaderAndFooter at : " + i.ToString() + "\r\n"; }
    i++;
}
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Seems the order is always RangeSelector = 0, HeaderAndFooter = 1. Even if I call the following just prior to this:

```
this.mainPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.pnlRangeSelector, 1);
this.mainPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.headerAndFooterRowCounts, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which the controls are added to the Controls collection of the parent determines the z-order. So the best way to solve this (AFAIK) is to make a backup of the designer file and then edit the order in which the controls are **ADDED to the collection**

Post the code if you need help.

Comment: The controls are already added in the correct order (background panel first, foreground panel next).

Comment: declared or added to the collection? Could you post the code?

Comment: You need to reverse the order. Add the last one first... it is counter intuitive but I tested with two buttons on a form.

Comment: Swapping them around actually makes no difference, renders in exactly the same way.

Comment: It does make a difference to me. Any chance you can give a download of the entire code? I noticed that you need to close all files before editing the designer file.

Comment: I can't share the code, too difficult to extract anything that would build. I've linked to an example of what I've got, with Hawkeye used to check the z-ordering of the panels. Shows that the panel that should take up the top seems to have the correct z-order. Basically with autosize turned off, the headerAndFooterRowCount should just take up the bottom right corner.

Comment: Seems calling both BringToFront() and SendToBack() on pnlRangeSelector doesn't adjust the order of those 2 items in Hawkeye :S

Comment: In my sample I never touched z-ordering. I am afraid it is a rare combination of values that causes this. Just adding two controls and switching the order in which they are added to the parent changes their layout/docking.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found the problem was in the Designer code.  In my base form, caseHeader was docked to the top.  Then, I added formInstructions and docked it to the top.  Therefore, my base had formInstructions below the caseHeader.  This is the desired appearance.

In derived forms, the appearance was reversed.  I researched about docking, autosize, z-orders, etc. - all to no avail.

Finally, I found Designer was changing the child indices of various controls.  This is what I did in the Designer code to fix the problem:

```
//this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.caseHeader, 0);
```

Comment: This is closer to identifying the source of the problem: for me for a particular control and probably for others, Designer is subverting the Z-Order by calling `SetChildIndex()`. However, if you comment it out in Designer, Designer will revert your edit on the next save. So this is not a solution.